# Max session 1 is not working with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to restrict only one max session for a single user in my application where i am using spring boot and java based config.I used spring max session 1. But its not working for me.
    This is my java based spring configuration file

```
package com.prcvideoplt.prc;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.prcvideoplt.handlers.LoginFailureHandler;
import com.prcvideoplt.handlers.LoginSuccessHandler;
import com.prcvideoplt.handlers.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.prcvideoplt.service.security.CompanyBasedCustomFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.prcvideoplt")
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "custUserDetails")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(13);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(value = 1)
    public static class UserWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Resource(name = "loginSuccessHandler")
        private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;
        @Resource(name = "loginFailureHandler")
        private LoginFailureHandler loginFailureHandler;
        @Resource(name = "logoutSuccesshandler")
        private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccesshandler;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
        }

        @Bean
        public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
        }

        @Bean
        public CompanyBasedCustomFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            CompanyBasedCustomFilter authFilter = new CompanyBasedCustomFilter();
            authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authenticate", "POST"));
            authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(loginSuccessHandler);
            authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(loginFailureHandler);
            authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            return authFilter;
        }

        @Override
        @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
            JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
            tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return tokenRepositoryImpl;
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
            SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
            return sessionRegistry;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(new String[]{"/user/**"}).hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                    .hasAnyRole(new String[]{"ADMIN", "SUB_ADMIN"}).antMatchers(new String[]{"/**"}).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/check-url-pattern").loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password").permitAll().and().addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .rememberMe().key("rem-me-key").rememberMeParameter("remember-me").rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me")
                    .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().logout().logoutUrl("/invalidate")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccesshandler).invalidateHttpSession(true).and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
                    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/expired").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: It allows a single user of my application to login from multiple browsers

Comment: I want to restrict that thing.

Comment: Again what isn't working and HOW are you testing.. Opening a new browser window isn't going to work as that will share the session. You need to test with 2 separate browsers (i.e chrome and firefox for instance).

Comment: Yes i am testing it with different brwosers chrome and Firefox but same user gets logged in from both the browser.

Comment: No previous session doesn't get expired.Its not working for me.

Comment: I even tested it by removing the custom filter UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter that i was using and remember me configuration but its not working and allow multiple logins from multiple browsers.

Comment: Login page is at the root of my application("/")  http://localhost:8080/prc-application/

Comment: "/authenticate"  for login form

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove

```
 @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your webConfigSecurity class

```
http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl("/")
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/login?invalid-session=true");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating a Bean HttpSessionEventPublisher

```
   @Bean
   HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

You should take as a consideration this point:

"**If you are using the custom UserDetails instance, make sure you override equals() and hashCode() methods**.

By default Spring security SessionRegistry implementation uses an in-memory map to store the UserDetails. If you are using a custom UserDetails without equals() and hashCode() methods, it won’t be able to match the user correctly. Also, the default UserDetails object from Spring security provides implementation for both equals() and hashCode() methods."

References:

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-session/

https://youtube.com/watch?v=rWIVa-nTX6Q&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merely creating `HttpSessionEventPublisher` make sure you register it as a session event listener:

```
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can still login with same user from different browsers and none of the previous session gets expired.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do it in a simple spring boot way,Go to your WebSecurityConfig Class in your case it's called SpringSecurityConfig

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
     }
```