# Cannot set concurrent session control in spring-boot with maximumSessions and maxSessionsPreventsLogin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to establish concurrent session control with non-xml Spring Security, so a user can't log in if he is already logged in in another device. I used `.sessionManagement() .maximumSessions(1) .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)`, but using Chrome and Firefox I still can log in concurrently.

I have tried configuring `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as instructed by [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914208/max-session-1-is-not-working-with-spring-boot), but I'm still able to log in concurrently.

This is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired 
    UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
       return new DinamicaUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", 
                             "/home", 
                             "/about", 
                             "/registro", 
                             "/session-error",
                             "/img/**",
                             "/img/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
             .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/session-error")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }

}
```

I expect it to show an error if I try to log in in Chrome while still logged in in Firefox, but the second concurrent login is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the session, session registry compare the the object of `UserDetails` to check if there is already a session for that principal.

Since you are using a custom UserDetails service `DinamicaUserDetailsService`, you should override hashcode and equals method to make sure they are matched for same user. For example you can compare user id or any other unique attribute of user.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object user) {
    if(user == null) return false;
    return (user.getId() == getId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After adding your suggestion, it already throws an error while triying to log in concurrently - solved